# Azure ioT hub/Raspberry Pi Remote monitoring hiccup

Tags: raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

This is likely to be a lengthy one and I am really hoping someone has the time and patience to assist me before the 14th June 2017.  I have jumped on an IoT opportunity at work for a customer that needs a solution built using Azure IoT suite.  For those of you reading this that are keen on a pretty sweet project, feel free to follow the walkthrough to see if you end up on the same snag. The walkthrough is pretty detailed, see below:

1) azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/#section2.8

So what I have done is I have setup an Rpi3 with Raspian Lite (headless).  The walkthrough suggests using an Adafruit BME280 multi-sensor which I haven't connected yet, but I will be buying one this week to do that.  I didn't think it would be necessary to have it connected upfront as the majority of the steps in the walkthrough are about getting the Azure IoT Suite remote monitoring solution setup.  The pi setup is straight forward and for me to connect to it I used **raspi-config** to enable SSH and are able to connect to the device without a glitch.

Everything in the walkthrough goes as expected on the pi up until the point where I get to **step 1.6**.  In this step there is a line that suggests running the following code:

```
~/iot-hub-c-raspberrypi-getstartedkit/samples/build.sh
```

See the following image:

[Image 1:  This is where **build.sh** code initially fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV8HL.jpg)

[Image 2: This is where **build.sh** continues to fail and then quits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMxU7.jpg)

So, considering I am a sales guy with very limited technical expertise, and consider myself more of a tinkerer than a seasoned coder, the C code in this **build.sh**, seems to hit a snag and my problem is that I cannot seem to understand what the failure reason is trying to tell me.  I'd really appreciate anyone's assistance here as I'm scrambling for time to have this up and running for my customer meeting before the 14th June 2017.  If anyone has the capacity to assist me, I'd **really** appreciate it more than you know :-)

Comment: Hi, I'd recommend you look at this equivalent but more detailed tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-c-get-started.

Comment: Thanks Dominic.  I'll give that a go :-)

Comment: You can run the following command in the terminal to check that wiringPi is installed or not: `gpio -v`.